# If someone performed an arbitrage, is it possible to see the smart contract he executed if I know his wallet address?

Tags: solidity, bsc, smart-contract-wallets

For example if I look at an address like this:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xfbe65ad3eed6b28d59bf6043debf1166d3420d214020ef54f12d2e0583a66f13

I can see the transactions, but is it possible to see what smart contract was responsible to create these transactions?

I assume no, or at best you can only see the byte code but not the original solidity source code?

Comment: By the way, what's that tx? It is definitely not a regular arbitrage. It looks like some kind of exploit using flash loans.

Comment: Yep, just like I thought: https://coinmarketcap.com/headlines/news/autoshark-finance-is-the-latest-victim-to-the-third-flash-loan-attack-on-binance-smart-chain-in-a-week/

Comment: oh yes one article was saying it's a complex arb that's why i said arb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

In the transaction that you linked to in your question, the person call a function `swap()` directly on the pair contract. The [code of the pair](https://bscscan.com/address/0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16#code) contract is public (verified). So, in that case, yes you can see exactly what the public contract did when called.

However, calling the `swap()` function on a pair directly is a very bad way of doing arbitrages and it is actually the first time that I see that. Normally, the arbitrageur will call a function on a custom contract that is not public (verified). In that case, you cannot know what the custom contract is doing exactly and can only see the final result.

EDIT: After looking carefully at the transaction above, it is in fact indirectly using a [custom contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x22de6648685e4e47fd944e68b264e0e0667e2e00) that is not verified, so it is very hard to know what was done exactly by that custom contract.

Comment: thx a lot. how did you know he called swap directly? if you don't do this, how can you do a swap using pancake or uniswap using code? like swap my BNB with ETH for example? do they have an API? i had the impression the API is the public contract.

Comment: The To address is a pancake swap pair, so it is a function of that contract that was called directly. Also, the Input Data line on bscscan shows that the swap function was called.

Comment: thx a lot also you linked the custom contract but bscscan also allows decompiling this byte code, though not as readable, isn't this the same smart contract that he used? just not the original source code but the decompiled one?

Comment: Yes it's the same, but good luck trying to understand decompiled contracts without the source code!

Comment: thx man :) .....